# Usabe of pyinstaller with opencl

Tags: opencl, pyinstaller

What is the correct way on converting a python script to binary using pyinstaller and opencl? How do I setup the name.spec file? See my pyinstaller settings below

Usage: pyinstaller --clean --noconfirm --log-level=DEBUG --onefile --paths=/home/testuser/projects/tool --paths=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyopencl-2018.2.2-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg  --hidden-import=pyopencl --name=toolexe tool.py

Comment: Could you describe the current issue faced by you while using the command?

Answer (score 0):

From my main script(myscript.py), I am calling "import tool as *", which is my tool package, and it's calling "import pyopencl as cl" in several tool package scripts. When I run the compiled binary version on my scripts, I see "pyopencl.**init**.py" being called multiple times.. (see diagram below)
I am wondering if it's the relative import of "tool as *", that screwing up the binary version. Note: This code does work as python script code.

> #myscript -- "import tool as *"
> └── tool
> ├── common.py ... #"import pyopencl as cl"
> ├── engine.py ... #"import pyopencl as cl"
> ├── traffic.py... #"import pyopencl as cl"
> ├── **init**.py

Answer (score 0):

I found two issue with my conversion python scripts to binary

1. The python script import tool/tool.py was wrong, you can't have import script with the same name as the directory it's in.
2. In linux, there is a warning with threading when converting to binary..
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

**Warning** The 'spawn' and 'forkserver' start methods cannot currently be used with “frozen” executables (i.e., binaries produced by packages like PyInstaller and cx_Freeze) on Unix. The 'fork' start method does work